# Recyclerview adapter not working inside onResume method of fragment in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I am trying to listen to a click event inside my onResume method of fragment. I have two fragments in my viewpager and if I use `onResume` in both the fragments only one of them is working other is not working. Below is what I am doing.

**Fragment 1**

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new catAdapterBlack.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String position, int pos, int posi, View v) {
         ... doing some stuff...
        }
    });


    subAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new subcatAdapter.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String position, int pos, View v) {
            ... doing some stuff...
    });
}
```

**Fragment 2**

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new catAdapterBlack.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String position, int pos, int posi, View v) {
         ... doing some stuff...
        }
    });


    subAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new subcatAdapter.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String position, int pos, View v) {
            ... doing some stuff...
    });
}
```

I am using the same adapters in both the fragments.

Now when i searched here i found this solution below but it's also not working. When i open my first fragment the app crashes with error calling MyClickListener on a null object reference.So far i have tried every method. I tried calling onresume in first Fragment and the below (setUserVisibleHint)solution in fragment two. but again its not working while the app is not crashing this way. I want to call the Myclicklistener inside both the fragments.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        init();
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: where do you initialize your adapters?

Comment: inside a method which i am calling from onCreateView of fragment

Comment: sorry i have just checked i have initialised both the adapter in onCreateView and later called the method where i am adding the items into my list and notifying the adapter of the change

Comment: after you have initialized your adapter you can call the `setOnItemClickListener` no need to set the listener in the callback `onresume`.
It isn't too clear what you are trying to do and what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Move your code from `onResume` in `onCreateView` after you set the adapters.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
if(isVisibleToUser) {
    // Here you need to check if your adapter is not null and initialize your adapters again
} else {

}
}
```

All you need is to check if your adapter is not null you may need to initialize your adapter again.